# Convert a date format in another in Android?

Tags: android, date-format

I am getting date from server as response in format **MM/DD/YYYY in numeric as 8/14/2012**.

Now, I am in a need to convert this format from **8/14/2012** to **14 Aug 2012**.

Is it possible to do this with some in-built logic's or I need to prepare some custom code of Java to fetch the required format.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use date format for your requirement.

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
Date date = format1.parse("8/14/2012");
System.out.println(format2.format(date));// which prints 14 Aug 2012.
```

you can find various date formats [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
DateFormat[] formats = new DateFormat[] {
   DateFormat.getDateInstance(),
   DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(),
   DateFormat.getTimeInstance(),
 };
 for (DateFormat df : formats) {
   System.err.println(df.format(new Date(0)));
 }
```